# Rails Capistrano 3 - how to share production.log file into the shared folder of Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano 3 for deployment with my Rails app. The problem is that every time I deploy my app to the server the ./log/production.log file is reset. I've heard it's possible to have the production.log file into the shared folder and being appended at each deployment.

I thought this was made by default by Capistrano but apparently not for me :(

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your config/deploy.rb you need a line similar to this:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{log public/system}
```

This will tell capistrano to symlink `log` and `public/system` into the shared directory on deployment.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I wanted. But why `public/system`, I don't have this folder?

Comment: Ah, that's just what I have.  In production we store assets on S3.  In staging we don't, they go into public/system/sub/folders.  So we symlink that so it doesn't get blown away while deploying staging.

Comment: Alright. I also had to add the `public/assets` folder to the `linked_dirs` because of this https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/52